# How to delete all columns of a row using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have the following code to delete the columns of a table:

```
let xvm = document.getElementsByClassName("removedor");
let k = 0
let y = document.querySelectorAll('td')
let ya = document.querySelectorAll('td').length
let z = document.querySelectorAll('th')
let za = document.querySelectorAll('th').length
let restaurador = document.getElementsByClassName('restaurador');


for (let k = 0; k < za; k++) {
  let xvm = document.getElementsByClassName("removedor");
  let y = document.querySelectorAll('td')
  let ya = document.querySelectorAll('td').length
  let z = document.querySelectorAll('th')
  let za = document.querySelectorAll('th').length
  let restaurador = document.getElementsByClassName('restaurador');
  document.getElementsByClassName("removedor")[k].addEventListener("click", function() {
    z[k].style.display = "none";
    y[k].style.display = "none";
  })
}
```

The code works with only the first row when i click to delete the columns. I want it to delete the column that i clicked from all the rows from the table.

Comment: When deleting `all columns of a row`, aren't you just trying to `delete a row` ? Try to get the row element and delete it. And also, do you want to delete it OR to just hide it?  .

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a *class* to each *delete* button, then run a **forEach loop** over that ***nodelist*** and check for a click. When the click hits use the ***event.target*** and head up the ***nodelist*** to the nearest parent element to add a verification => `e.target.closest('td')` this will give you the table data element your button is residing within. Then you can insert a verification to make sure the user wishes to delete or not, getting the id of the row =>

```js
td.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ` <label class="checkLabel">Delete ${row}? <input type="checkbox" class="checkYes"></label>`);
```

A second event listener to check if the class we add into the DOM for the check is present in the DOM => `checkYes.addEventListener('change', deleteRow);`  if this is not present we add the HTML that will delete the row.

`checkYes.addEventListener('change', deleteRow);`

The function to deleteRow:

```js
function deleteRow(e){
  e.target.closest('tr').remove();
}
```

I did not add a toggle for the delete button, but you could also add a toggle to the delete button that will hide the secondary verification if you hit the delete button again.

```js
const del = document.querySelectorAll('.del');

function deleteRow(e) {
  e.target.closest('tr').remove();
}

function checkDel(e) {
  let td = e.target.closest('td');
  let row = e.target.closest('tr').id;
  if (!td.querySelector('.checkYes')) {
    td.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ` <label class="checkLabel">Delete ${row}? <input type="checkbox" class="checkYes"></label>`);
  }
  let checkYes = td.querySelector('.checkYes');
  checkYes.addEventListener('change', deleteRow);
}

del.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', checkDel);
})
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr id="row_1">
    <td>Row 1 Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 Col 3</td>
    <td>Row 1 Col 4</td>
    <td><button class="del">Delete this row</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row_2">
    <td>Row 2 Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 2 Col 3</td>
    <td>Row 2 Col 4</td>
    <td><button class="del">Delete this row</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row_3">
    <td>Row 3 Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 3 Col 3</td>
    <td>Row 3 Col 4</td>
    <td><button class="del">Delete this row</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i need to delete the columns of all the rows instead of the row itself. I figured it out and it is working now.